# Initializing base with rvalue reference of derived

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor, move-semantics

In the following code:

```
struct A {
    A() {}
    A(A &&) { printf("moving A\n"); }
    ~A() { printf("destructing A\n"); }
};

struct B : A {
    B() {}
    B(B &&) { printf("moving B\n"); }
    ~B() { printf("destructing B\n"); }
};

B func() {
    B b;
    return b;
}

int main() {
    A a = func();
    printf("hello\n");
}
```

The following output is produced:

```
moving A
destructing B
destructing A
hello
destructing A
```

Why isn't the move elided? Why is the move constructor of A called but not that of B? What's actually happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the move constructor of A called but not that of B?

Because you're constructing an `A`, then only `A`'s constructors will be considered. Particularly, the temporary `B` returned by `func()` could bind to `A&&`, then `A`'s move constructor is used to construct `a`; in ohter word, `a` is sliced from the temporary `B`.

> Why isn't the move elided?

[Copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) is not allowed for this case, `a` has to be constructed from the temparary `B`.

> First, if `T` is a class type and the initializer is a prvalue expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as `T`, the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object: see [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

`func()` returns a `B`, which is not the same type as `A` exactly.

Comment: Why did a destructor call to `B` occur before `A`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 When the temporary `B` is destroyed, `B`'s destructor is called firstly then its base class i.e. `A`'s destructor is called.

Comment: Why is A destructed twice if it's moved?

Comment: @wispi The first one happens when the temporary `B` is destroyed, which includes the invocatioin of `B`'s destructor and `A`'s destructor. Even the temporary `B` is moved it still needs to be desconsructed. The 2nd one happens when `a` is destroyed.